# IIS URL rewriting fails

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to implement simple IIS URL rewrite. I want to rewrite URL: **about.test.local** to **text.local/about.html** .

In configuration below I have added rules, but it doesn't seem to work. What is the problem?

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite1" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="about.test.local" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test.local/about.html" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rewrite2" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="http://about.test.local/" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test.local/about.html" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

As @beavel mentioned, I have added following rules, but URL still doesn't get rewritten:

```
            <rule name="Rewrite2a" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.+)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="about.test.local" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test.local/about.html" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rewrite2b" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.+)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://about.test.local/" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test.local/about.html" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the "User-friendly URL" template from the URL Rewrite module GUI to help set this up? I haven't done a ton with rewriting itself, so I'm not certain if my answer fully corrects the problem. I started out with what I knew was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the match url doesn't contain the host as explained [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule). If you have multiple hostnames bound to one IIS site and only want to rewrite the one hostname you would do something like:

```
<rule name="Rewrite1" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.+)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="about.test.local" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test.local/about.html" />
</rule>
```